# Python, how to write a message that includes a tuple and a string of characters when using input?

Tags: python-3.x, input

I am trying to write a message to the user that contains a tuple and string something like

`(0,0) what is your move:`
i tried the following:

`x= input((0,0)+ "what is your move: ")` cant concatenate str with tuple

`x= input((0,0), "what is your move: ")` input takes a max of 1 arg

`x= input(((0,0), "whats your move))"` result: `(0,0) whats your move: )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to convert the tuple to a string first:

```
x = input(str((0,0)) + " what is your move: ")
```

Though it would be cleaner to use the `str.format` method:

```
x = input("{} what is your move: ".format((0,0)))
```

Comment: awesome, thanks a lot